# Flutter How Can I reach another class func?

Tags: flutter

```
class _AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicatorState
    extends State<_AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicator>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
   late AnimationController  _animationController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,

      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
    );

  }
   void checkWork() {
     _animationController.repeat();
     _animationController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
   }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final percentage = _animationController.value * 100;
   
    if(per <= _animationController.value * 100){
      _animationController.stop();
    }

    return Row(
      children: [
        LiquidCustomProgressIndicator(
          value: _animationController.value ,
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.red),
          shapePath: _buildHeartPath(),
          center: Text(
            "${percentage.toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
   
      ],


    );
```

I want to call "checkWork" function in another class button but when I tried this I get error
"LateInitializationError: Field '_animationController@29217585' has not been initialized."
Actually I don't know how to reach that function.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues, first of all your `_AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicatorState` class is private and that is why you can't call it from another class. Unless your other class is located in the same file as `_AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicatorState`.

You have two options:

> Keep private class:
>
> If you want to keep it private, you can create the other class in the same file where your private class exists. It would look something like this:

```dart
    class AnotherClass {
        // ... Whatever you want to do in here
        final animatedProgressIndicator =
            _AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicatorState() // You create the object.

        void someFunction() {
            // How you can now call the method.
            animatedProgressIndicator.checkWork();
        }
    }

    class _AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicatorState
    extends State<_AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicator>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
        // ...
        void checkWork() {
            // Whatever you want to execute...
        }
        // ...
    }
```

If not, you can also:

> Change your class to public:
>
> Just remove `_` from your class name, making it now `AnimatedLiquidCustomProgressIndicatorState`.
> Here you can do the same as before, but `AnotherClass` can now be in a different file.

**Finally**, the `"LateInitializationError: Field '_animationController@29217585' has not been initialized."` error it's because of this:

Instead of initializing your `AnimationController` with late, like:

```dart
late AnimationController  _animationController;
```

do this:

```dart
AnimationController?  _animationController;
```

That should do it.

Comment: "LateInitializationError: Field '_animationController@29217585' has not been initialized." I tried first soliton but ı got same error

Comment: ohhh yes, I think I see where the problem is, I'll submit another answer :)

Comment: @Emre I updated my answer, it should work now! You were initializing your AnimationController with `late`.